# Scala: Parsing json using asOpt[T] return None although I have value

Tags: json, scala

I'm trying to extract value using asOpt[T] as I may not have the key. I get in return None although I have a value in my string.

```
val jsonString = {"data": {"operation":"+", "value":"1"},"right": {"data":{"operation":"-", "value":"2"}},"left":{"data":{"operation":"-", "value":"4"}}}
buildFromJson(jsonString)
```

Code:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
...
def buildFromJson(jsonString: String) : TreeNode = {
    val nodeData = json.\("data")
    val nodeValue = nodeData.\("operation").as[String] //This works

    println("left= " + json.\("left").asOpt[String]) //output= None
    println("left= " + json.\("left").as[String]) // throws exception
    println("left= " + json.\("left").toString) //output= {"data":{"operation":"-", "value":"4"}}
```

What is the best way to parse JSON key that might not exist? As I read it is asOpt, but it doesn't work.

Update - How I overcome the problem:

1) First of all m-z was right, it was indeed object and could not return as String.

2) I couldn't find a good way to extract field that might not be exist (as at the beginning I added 'right' to json only if right sub node was exist). Now I add to the json 'right' field with null value if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `left` is an object, and not a `String`

Comment: So how can I check if `left` is `null` before I'm converting it to a `String`?

Comment: Why would you want to convert it to a `String` and not an object?

Comment: Since this method is recursive and I prefer to send it strings

Comment: I've change the method to receive json object. How do I check if the value is null/None? I get `JsUndefined` and I cannot understand how to use it in my stop condition

Comment: Are you using asOpt[JsObject]?  If so, are you saying that you are returned a Some[JsUndefined]?   That would be surprising.

Comment: This is the statement: `if (!json.\("right").as[JsValue].equals(JsUndefined))`. I tried to compare to None/null/JsUndefined - nothing works

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a value is None but this is generaly a bad idea. It leads to obscure code with tons of pattern matching/error handling code/if/etc ... The good news is `Option` and `JsResult` are both monads! You can use the one you like but i prefer `JsResult` as it gives error messages while `Option` just gives you `None` (it's always better to know where to look for an error than to have to test each line).

Assuming you have an alegraic data type TreeNode :

```
abstract class TreeNode
case class Leaf(operation : String, value : String) extends TreeNode
case class Node(l : Leaf, left : TreeNode, right : TreeNode) extends TreeNode
```

The parsing function could be:

```
def buildTreeNode(json: JsValue) : JsResult[TreeNode] =
    for {operation <- (json \ "data" \ "operation").validate[String]
         value     <- (json \ "data" \ "value").validate[String]
         leaf      = Leaf(operation, value)
         left      <- (json \ "left").validate[Option[JsObject]]
         right     <- (json \ "right").validate[Option[JsObject]]
         result    <- (left , right) match {
             case (Some(l), Some(r)) => for { leftnode  <- buildTreeNode(l)
                                              rightNode <- buildTreeNode(r)
                                        } yield Node(leaf, leftnode, rightNode)
             case (None   , None   ) => JsSuccess(leaf)
             case (_      , _      ) => JsError("left or right is missing")
         }
    } yield result
```

The code tries to find `operation` and `value` fields under `data`. If one if these line fails, the computation is stoped and an error message indicating the erorr is returned. On success, the computation continues and tries to find left and right fields. If they are present and valid `JsObject` they are parsed recursively. If none is present, this node is a leaf. Otherwise, there is an error.

This code, while being easy to read, performs a lot of error handling, no exceptions and returns not so bad error messages

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to add it to my code, but I had a problem. TreeNode/Node is abstract and I have 3 types of nodes that I need to choose from depends on 'operation' value. At the end I solved the problem by adding 'right'/'left' in any case, and in case there isn't sub node give null value.